# Meteor & react: Alternate way to load the required tinymce script scripts instead on <script></script> tag

Tags: reactjs, meteor, tinymce

Sometimes when developing with react you need to put stuff such as:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

But also I already installed it via npm:

```
npm install tinymce
```

And created a custom component:

```
//React required imports
import tinymce from 'tinymce';

class DummyEditor extends Component {

   componentDidMount(){
      tinymce.init({
        //DO intializationn stuff there
      })
   }
}
```

So I am trying to make to use the npm installed version without the need to put the `<script></script>` tag to the `<head></head>` of `client/main.html`

So I tried to do the following:

```
//React required imports
import tinymce from 'tinymce';

class DummyEditor extends Component {
    
       componentwillMount(){

         window.myVars={
           tinymce:tinymce
         }

       }

       componentDidMount(){
          tinymce.init({
            //DO intializationn stuff there
          })
       }
    }
```

And the following:

Create a file named `myTinymce.js`:

```
import tinymce from './myTinymce';
window.tinymce=tinymce;
export default tinymce;
```

And then use it to my component

```
 //React required imports
import tinymce from './myTinymce';

class DummyEditor extends Component {
    
       componentwillMount(){

         window.myVars={
           tinymce:tinymce
         }

       }

       componentDidMount(){
          tinymce.init({
            //DO intializationn stuff there
          })
       }
    }
```

But in both actions I get:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  theme.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]  plugin.js:1
>
> TypeError: t is not a constructor[Μάθετε Περισσότερα]

Do you fellows have3 an Idea how to dynamically load scripts (or the tinymce script)that affect the global scope or event NOT to load them and have the same result is downloaded via npm?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `getScript` method. Configure TinyMCE in the callback of `getScript` and keep a selector in the `render`  method.   Keep a flag in the `state` which will be updated when `TinyMCE` is loaded and update to state will `rerender` the component.

Hope following code snippet helps:

```
componentDidMount(){
    let context = this;
    $.getScript('https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js', function(){
      context.setState({
        loading: false
      });

      tinymce.init({
         selector:'#mytextarea',
         plugins: 'code, image, textcolor, table',
         toolbar: ["undo | redo | italic | bold <and other options>"]
       });
    });
  }
```

And, in `render` method just keep a textarea with the same ID:

```
<textarea id='mytextarea'></textarea>
```